# Creating relative position for observation

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have some trouble creating the "wanted.column" in my data set. The data is sorted on date and company (panel data), and I want to know the relative position compared to the event for each company (dummy variable = 1 if event occurs). Have tried by using group_by in loop but can't get it to work. Thankful for any help I can get.

```
data <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(17358, 17359, 17360, 17361, 
                              17364, 17365, 17366, 17367, 17368, 17371, 17372,
                              17358, 17359, 17360, 17361, 
                              17364, 17365, 17366, 17367, 17368, 17371, 17372), class = "Date"), 
           Ret = c(-0.012, 0.023, -0.002, 0.004, -0.006, 
                     -0.014, -0.019, -0.005, -0.006, -0.011, -0.019,
                   -0.012, 0.023, -0.002, 0.004, -0.006, 
                   -0.014, -0.019, -0.005, -0.006, -0.011, -0.019
           ), Company = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                          "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                          "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                          "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
           ), Dummy = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 1, 
                        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
                        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 1, 
                        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
           ), wanted.column = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                                -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
           )), row.names = 1:22, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could subtract the `row_number` from the position where `Dummy == 1` for each `Company`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(Company) %>% 
   mutate(new_col = if(all(is.na(Dummy))) NA else row_number() - which.max(Dummy))

#   DATE          Ret Company Dummy wanted.column new_col
#   <date>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>         <dbl>   <int>
# 1 2017-07-11 -0.012 A          NA            -4      -4
# 2 2017-07-12  0.023 A          NA            -3      -3
# 3 2017-07-13 -0.002 A          NA            -2      -2
# 4 2017-07-14  0.004 A          NA            -1      -1
# 5 2017-07-17 -0.006 A           1             0       0
# 6 2017-07-18 -0.014 A          NA             1       1
# 7 2017-07-19 -0.019 A          NA             2       2
# 8 2017-07-20 -0.005 A          NA             3       3
# 9 2017-07-21 -0.006 A          NA             4       4
#10 2017-07-24 -0.011 A          NA             5       5
# … with 12 more rows
```

In base R, using the same logic we can use `ave` :

```
data$new_col <- with(data, ave(Dummy, Company, FUN = function(x) 
                if(all(is.na(x))) NA else  seq_along(x) - which.max(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak! For some reason I get the following error code when trying it on my data: 

Error: Column `new_col` must be length 3523 (the group size) or one, not 0. -

Do you know what might be the problem? I have some companies that just have NAs in the Dummy variable column, i.e. the event never occurred. Can that be the problem?

Comment: @Herrn yes, that is the issue. If all are `NA`s what you want output to be? All `NA`s ?

Comment: Updated the answer to handle that case.

Comment: Hi again @Ronak! Ran into some trouble with the code above as some companies have the same event occurring multiple times. Is there a possibility to limit the new column to only show values between -20 and 20 for instance? As of now, each company's observations are only in relation to its first event.

Comment: Do you mean to add `%>% filter(new_col > -20 & new_col < 20)` to the above answer?

Comment: No, I would want to have the event window for each event and company. The problem is that for companies with multiple events, the relative position is only in relation to the first dummy.

Comment: @Herrn I think it is better to ask a new question on this as this doesn't look related to your original question. Extending questions in comments invalidates current answers and creates confusion for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,  if(all(is.na(Dummy))) NA_integer_ else .N - which.max(Dummy), by = Company]
```